# Change close button of a modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap modal, however I want to customize the close button but so far to no avail.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem or how can I solve it?

Thanks

[My Modal -- DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/jjNFSLmgjT)

**HTML**

Launch demo modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could customize `css` of the `span` inside the `.close` button.
For example, this could do the trick:

```
.close span {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
```